# Calculation of Amount for single day excluding the amount from another day for the same order on a single machine

Tags: sql

I have this data, I have to calculate the total amount produced on one day on a single machine(group by Machine no.) from different orders, but the amount given here also includes the amount which was produced another day, I only have to include the amount produced in current day’s shift.

I thought of comparing the `booked_from` and `booked_till` dates in order to find out whether the order is continued from previous day, and then subtracting the previous day amount from current day amount, but it doesn’t work out. I have to only consider the date part, for that I have generated a stored procedure. Rownumber field I added from myself to make it more convenient to work with the records.

I had the query to sum up the amount produced on single day including the previous days amount, but the requirement is to subtract the previous days amount from current day's amount.

I would really appreciate any suggestions regarding this problem…

```
Orderno Booked_from ---------Booked_till    --------Amount(Kg) --M/cNo. --Row no.   --Finished

201202  12.05.2013 07:00:00 13.05.2013 07:00:00 500--------100    ------1   ----------- 0

201202  13.05.2013 07:42:00 13.05.2013 14:32:00 600--------100  ------2 ----------- 0

201209  13.05.2013 11:00:00 14.05.2013 08:00:20 0-----------110 ------3 ----------- 0

201202  13.05.2013 15:00:00 14.05.2013 15:00:00 1500-------100  -----4  ----------- 1

201209  14.05.2013 15:10:30 15.05.2013 11:00:00 150--------110  ------5 ------------0

201209  15.05.2013 12:10:30 15.05.2013 18:00:00 200--------110  ------6 ------------0

201209  15.05.2013 19:00:00 16.05.2013 07:00:00 600--------110  ------7 ------------1

201212  16.05.2013 08:10:30 16.05.2013 11:00:00 0-----------100 ------8 ------------0

201212  16.05.2013 11:10:30 16.05.2013 13:00:00 200--------100  ------9 ------------0

201212  16.05.2013 13:20:30 16.05.2013 15:00:00 400--------100  -----10 ------------1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should include this logic.

```
where yourDateTimeField >= Date1
and yourDateTimeField < Date2
```

in your particular case, Date2 is the day after Date1.  Let us know if you have trouble implementing this logic.

Comment: Thank you :) I would let you know after implementing this logic into my query

Comment: I tried, but I didn't understood what is the logic behind this, as I don't have a particular shift time for a day, it can be any time of the day